# Lie algebra of $Gl(V)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is the mean of bijective is an open condition ? And why the Lie algebra of $Gl(V)$ can be identified with $gl(V)$ ?

> [image]

Comment: It's an open condition because an linear endomorphism $T$ of a $n$-dimensional vector space is bijective if and only if $\det T\ne 0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli   I know endomorphism is bijective iff  $\det T\ne 0$. But I don't know the mean of open condition. What is open condition ?

Comment: A condition is open if the set of the elements which satisfy it is open.